# Laravel 5.7 View Render Bug on Paragraph

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Seems there's a problem on Laravel 5.7.11 view when rendering `<p>` element that contains child node.

Check the following code:

```
return view("main");
```

main.blade.php

```
<html>
<body>
<p><div>Inside Div</div></p>
<p><h5>Inside H5</h5></p>
<p>Just Plain Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the output of the code:

```
<html class="gr__localhost">
<head></head>
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
   <p></p><div>Inside Div</div><p></p>
   <p></p><h5>Inside H5</h5><p></p>
   <p>Just Plain Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that view cannot render `<p>` that has child nodes since it was able to render `<p>` containing plain text only while both `<div>` and `<h5>` got rendered outside `<p>`

I tried with different elements and only `<p>` has this problem.

Did anyone encounter this already?

Comment: Laravel 5.0 also produces the same result. Does anyone knows the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` tag inside a `<p>` tag is not a valid HTML. From HTML spec:

> **A p element’s end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by** an address, article, aside, blockquote, details, **div**, dl, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, main, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul, element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is an HTML element that is not an a, audio, del, ins, map, noscript, or video element.

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-html51-20160602/grouping-content.html)

The closing `<\p>` tag is likely added by your browser, not Laravel. Same applies to heading elements.

Comment: Nice! Tried editing at Browser level and the browser automatically added it. Thanks for your help!